# Selected Item in dataTable Primeng and Angular 4 find index -1

Tags: angular, primeng

Hi everyone i want to select item for delete and edit, i don't use CRUD dataTable of Primeng i use ng-template and column

So My code like this

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="users" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedUser" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [paginator]="true" rows="15" [responsive]="true">
    <p-column field="nom" header="Nom" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="email" header="Email" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Modfier" [sortable]="true">
            <ng-template let-col let-user="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                <button type="button" pButton (click)="editUser(user)" tooltipPosition="top" icon="fa fa-pencil"></button>
            </ng-template>

    </p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Supprimer" [sortable]="true">
        <ng-template let-col let-user="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <button type="button" pButton (click)="deleteUser(user)" tooltipPosition="top" icon=" fa fa-trash"></button>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

and when i click to delete user i need first the index so i call this function in component

```
findSelectedUserIndex(): number {
        return this.users.indexOf(this.selectedUser);
 }
```

but when i click in deleteUser

```
 deleteUser(user:User){
        console.log(user);
        console.log("here",this.findSelectedUserIndex());
    }
```

and this functions to get rowselected

```
 onRowSelect(event) {
        this.newUser = false;
        this.user = this.cloneUser(event.data);
        this.displayDialog = true;
    }

    cloneUser(c: User): User {
        let usr = new User();
        for(let prop in c) {
            usr[prop] = c[prop];
        }
        return usr;
    }
```

i get user with all data 
  but in  this.findSelectedUserIndex() i get -1 
 so anyone can help me to resolve this issue and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `rowIndex` to your ng-template and pass it when delete is clicked as

```
<p-column field="color" header="Supprimer" [sortable]="true">
        <ng-template let-col let-user="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            <button type="button" pButton (click)="deleteUser(user,i)" tooltipPosition="top" icon=" fa fa-trash"></button>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

Your method should be as

```
deleteUser(user:User,index:number){
        console.log(user);
        console.log("here",index);
    }
```